# Hosting Windows Forms controls in native windows, window class="Static"

Tags: winforms, winforms-interop

I need to provide a Windows Forms control to a native application (Visual Studio).
So I create a control and provide its handle.

Then, when I check the native window using Spy++, I see that my control is wrapped in additional 'control' with window class = "Static" and title "This is a static!". I have several problems with it:

1. Resize events sent to my control by a hosting window have to be re-sent to the "Static" so it also gets resized (otherwise my control get partially hidden within the static's size).
2. The static does not have `WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT`, which causes [KB149501](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149501) to appear (in short, whole application hangs on lost focus).
3. If I apply `WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT`, listbox within the static stops redrawing.

I think I have been doing something wrong, but I am not sure what. Google does not help, since static is a C# keyword as well so it occurs quite often in WinForms results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mostly solved the redrawing problem using DoubleBuffered=True, so probably this is it.
I still think I am doing something wrong, but at least it works now.